# JHipster Microservice Maven Build Failure (Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE)

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to build a JHipster Microservice using Maven, but whenever I use a profile other than Dev I just get the following error message

```
Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
```

JHipster 4.5.1

pom.xml

```
<configuration>
    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
    <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://serverdetails;</url>
    <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
    <username>myuser</username>
    <password>mypa$$word</password>
    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.company.project.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <logging>debug</logging>
</configuration>
```

application.yml

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://serverdetails;
    username: myuser
    password: mypa$$word
    hikari:
        data-source-properties:
            cachePrepStmts: true
            prepStmtCacheSize: 250
            prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
            useServerPrepStmts: true
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    database: SQL_SERVER
    show-sql: false
    properties:
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
```

Running my dev profile from IntelliJ works fine and connects to the database. Running Maven build against the dev profile also works fine. It's just when I switch to another one I get the below full stack trace.

```
2017-06-30 10:34:30.589  INFO 13148 --- [  restartedMain] com.company.project.MicroApi          : The following profiles are active: prod{profile.no-liquibase}
2017-06-30 10:34:36.373  INFO 13148 --- [  restartedMain] c.company.project.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod{profile.no-liquibase}
2017-06-30 10:34:36.516  INFO 13148 --- [  restartedMain] c.company.project.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2017-06-30 10:34:36.792  WARN 13148 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/company/project/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "prod{profile.no-liquibase}" are currently active).
2017-06-30 10:34:36.979  WARN 13148 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
2017-06-30 10:34:37.112 ERROR 13148 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
```

Do I need to include the jdbc driver in the project somewhere?

I've had a look at the following links that report similar problems, but their solutions didn't seem to make a difference to me (or I just didn't understand them);

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1610
[Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473319/cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type-none)
[Spring boot + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796818/spring-boot-hibernate)

Thanks for any help you can give.

Full Log below;

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\MyFolder "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=59123:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.4 spring-boot:run -P prod,no-liquibase,IDE,!dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Scrn Api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ microApi >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ microApi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 68 resources
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ microApi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 68 resources
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ microApi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ microApi ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\MyFolder\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\MyFolder\\target\\test-results\\coverage\\jacoco\\jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:build-info (default) @ microApi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ microApi ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 206 source files to C:\MyFolder\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ microApi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ microApi ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ microApi <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ microApi ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????
        ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????
  ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????
  ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????
   ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2017-06-30 12:57:51.837  INFO 4520 --- [           main] com.company.project.ScrnApiApp          : The following profiles are active: prod{profile.no-liquibase}
2017-06-30 12:57:57.706  INFO 4520 --- [           main] c.company.project.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod{profile.no-liquibase}
2017-06-30 12:57:57.845  INFO 4520 --- [           main] c.company.project.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2017-06-30 12:57:58.164  WARN 4520 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/company/project/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "prod{profile.no-liquibase}" are currently active).
2017-06-30 12:57:58.306  WARN 4520 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
2017-06-30 12:57:58.431 ERROR 4520 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "prod{profile.no-liquibase}" are currently active).

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.694 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-30T12:57:58+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/492M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project microApi: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've also tried adding the following dependency to the Pom.xml

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
                </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Gael, thanks for the reply. I've updated the original post to include the full log that I'm getting. Couldn't see a NullPointerException being caught anywhere though

Comment: `the profiles "prod{profile.no-liquibase}" are currently active` is suspicious to me and  could mean that your pom.xml is wrongly configured. Have you tried passing the profiles using the executable jar without maven?

Comment: It's looking like a config issue from my end as well. I reverted all config changes and started again and it's no longer throwing that error. If I get it working correctly I'll try and put some time aside to figure out what i'd done wrong and post it in here. Thanks again for your help Gael

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, I accidently deleted the

```
<driver>
```

tag from my pom

it must be set, mine looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
        <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:sqlserver://...</url>
        <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
        <username>your db name here</username>
        <password>password here</password>
        <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com...domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <logging>debug</logging>
    </configuration>
```